# Wordpress Ordering posts in foreach statement

Tags: wordpress, post, foreach

I have a for each statement that looks for a Taxonomy by ID and gets all termchildren and lists them using a foreach loop. I'm trying to figure out how to order them alphabetically by title. Here's my code:

```
$termID = 5;
$taxonomyName = "apartmentlocation";                        
$termchildren = get_term_children( $termID, $taxonomyName );

foreach ($termchildren as $child) {
    $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomyName);
    echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $term->name, $taxonomyName ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `get_terms()` instead, as it accepts a wider set of arguments.

```
//put your term and taxonomy variables here
$termID = 5;
$taxonomyName = "apartmentlocation"; 

$args = array(
    'child_of' => $termID,
    'orderby' => 'name', //this is the default, it actually isn't needed
    'order' => 'ASC' //this is the default as well
);
$termchildren = get_terms($taxonomyName, $args);

//do the rest of your loop
foreach ($termchildren as $child) {
    $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomyName);
    echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $term->name, $taxonomyName ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks xiankai, but I'm still having trouble. Can you give me a bit more detailed example?

Comment: I added in the remaining parts of your code - this is the complete code now. However I can't really help you much further without any idea what your trouble still is with this new code.

Comment: Your code produces the same result, the items are listed, but not ordered. If I comment out your $args array and get_terms line it seems to have no effect on the result. Thanks agin for your response!

Comment: My bad, I forgot to assign the results of `get_terms()` to `$termchildren`. Could you try it again? Otherwise it seems that you need to sort it manually via PHP.

Comment: No luck, your edit seems to have stopped the page from executing any code past where it's inserted. Anymore ideas? I found a [similar thread here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/17145/how-to-get-term-children-output-in-alphabetical-order) but wasn't able to follow and come through with a solution with my limited skills.

Comment: I'm not sure how my code could have broke your page, could you paste the complete code after editing?